# The method add(String) in the type ArrayList<String> is not applicable for the arguments (HashMap<String,String>)

Tags: android

How to fix this error The method add(String) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (HashMap).

I am trying to put androidhive.com xml parsing on custom listview on my application

heres my code:

```
private void prepareListData() {


    //ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ArrayList<String> songsList = new ArrayList<String>();


    com.test.utilities.XMLParser parser = new com.test.utilities.XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
    // looping through all song nodes <song>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
        map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
        map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsList.add(map);
    }

    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("VRP Medical Bay");
    //listDataHeader.add("");
    //listDataHeader.add("");

    // Adding child data

    ArrayList<String> listUnderVRP = new ArrayList<String>();

    //listUnderVRP.add("eDataClinical");
    //listUnderVRP.add("Schedule");
    //listUnderVRP.add("Dictate");
    //listUnderVRP.add("View Messages");
    //listUnderVRP.add("Reports for Signature");
    //listUnderVRP.add("View Billing");
    //listUnderVRP.add("View State");


    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), songsList); // Header, Child data
    //listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
    //listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
}
```

Comment: what error message do you get when you uncomment the line where you declare the array list as ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>

Comment: im getting error on this part  listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), songsList); The method put(String, ArrayList<String>) in the type HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>)

Answer (score 1):

> How to fix this error The method add(String) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (HashMap).

If you would like to call `add(HashMap<String, String>)` on your *songsList* `ArrayList`, obviously, you should daclare it as `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`. Otherwise `add` method expects a `String` (since your current songsList declared as `ArrayList<String>`).

Moreover, if then you would like to call `put` on your *listDataChild* `HashMap` and pass a `String` as a key and your *songsList* `ArrayList` as a value, you should declare it as `HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>`.

In other words:

```
private void prepareListData() {

   ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

   /* Same old code */

   /* 
    * Since listDataChild declared outside this method, do not forget to
    * replace the old declaration with 
    * HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> listDataChild;
    */
   listDataChild = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>();

   /* Same old code */
}
```

Pay attention to the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to declare `listDataChild = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();`

as

`listDataChild = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>();` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define your ArrayList like this  `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();` and it's good if you could post your stacktrace and it will help to track the error

Comment: i cant post image here, cause i still lack of points. my goal is, i got navigation drawer inside of it i got expandable list, i jst need to customized my listview, thats why i follow androidhive.com tutorial on custom listview, and i find it hard to implement it on my navigation with expandalist app

Answer (score 0):

To add a map object to your ArrayList you should define your ArrayList like below

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> songsList  = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>;
songsList.add(map);
```